# Adding Vue plugin in InertiaJS showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'show') error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I have this Component that I want to be available globally in my Inertia Laravel App

AlertSimple.vue

```js
<template>
    <div aria-live="assertive" class="...">
        <div class="...">
           
            <transition>
                <div v-if="showPopup"
                     class="..">
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <div >
                            <div >
                                <ExclamationCircleIcon v-if="type === 'error'" class="..."/>
                                <ExclamationTriangleIcon v-else-if="type === 'warn'" class="..."/>
                                <InformationCircleIcon v-else-if="type === 'info'" class="..."/>
                                <CheckCircleIcon v-else class="..."/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="...">
                                <p class="... capitalize">{{ title }}</p>
                                <p class="... normal-case">{{ content }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="...">
                                <button type="button" @click="showPopup = false"
                                        class="...">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                    <XMarkIcon class="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true"/>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </transition>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    
    props: {
        title: {type: String, required: true,},
        content: {type: String, required: true,},
        type: {type: String, required: false, default: 'success'},
        show: {type: Boolean, required: false, default: false},
        timeout: {type: Number, required: false, default: 5},
    },
    data() {
        return {
            showPopup: this.show,
            timer: null
        }
    },
    watch: {
        show: function (newVal, OldVal) {
            this.showPopUp();
        },
        content: function (){
            this.showPopUp()
        }
    },

    methods: {
        showPopUp() {
            this.showPopup = true;
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
            this.resetPopup();
        },
        resetPopup() {
            this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                this.showPopup = false;
            }, (this.timeout * 1000))
        }
    }

}


</script>
```

Instead of importing it in every component, I want to use it as follows:-

```js
this.$alertSimple.show(
  'Alert Title', 'Alert message', 'success', 5000
)
//Args as title, message, type, timeout.
```

Now, this is what I have:-

1. alert-simple-service.js

```js
import {render, h} from 'vue';
import AlertSimple from '../../Components/AlertSimple.vue';

const mountElement = (props) => {
    let el = document.createElement("div");
    let vNode = h(AlertSimple, props);

    render(vNode, el);

};

export default {
    show(title, content, show, type) {
        mountElement({title, content, show, type});
    }
}
```

2. alert-simple-plugin.js

```js
import service from '../../service/utility/alert-simple-service';

export default {
    install: (app, options) => {
        app.config.globalProperties.$alertSimple = service;
    }
}
```

3. app.js

This is how I initialize the app.

```js
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import {createApp, h} from 'vue';
import {createInertiaApp} from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import {resolvePageComponent} from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import {ZiggyVue} from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';
import alertSimplePlugin from './plugins/utility/alert-simple-plugin';


const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({el, App, props, plugin}) {
        return createApp({render: () => h(App, props)})
            .use(plugin)
            .use(alertSimplePlugin, {}) //This is where I am using the plugin
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#8000DE',
        showSpinner: true
    },
});
```

when I run the app and call my `this.$alertSimple.show(...)` I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'show')

This is what I changed in app.js.

```js
//I import service directly to app.js
import alertService from './service/utility/alert-simple-service'; 

//then I add it to VueApp variable in setup method.

//...

 setup({el, App, props, plugin}) {
        const VueApp = createApp({render: () => h(App, props)});

        VueApp.config.globalProperties.$alertSimple = alertService;

        VueApp.use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .mount(el);

        return VueApp;
 },

//...
```

This I saw [here](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/issues/287) but it does not solve the error.